# Does NumberLinePlot give the whole results over a large domain? Or we need to increase its precision?

Tags: plotting

I use this code over the domain $x\in(0,300)$

```
NumberLinePlot[
  1/2 (3 + x^2)^2 (7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + 9 Cos[2 π x] + 
      6 x^2 Cos[2 π x] + x^4 Cos[2 π x]) > 0, {x, 0, 300}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.01]]] /. _Point -> {}
```

then when I try it for $x\in(200,300)$, I see that there are more solutions on $(200,300)$ in comparison with the solutions of the same domain when I plotted it for $(0,300)$.

Mainly my question is, is the result of NumberLinePlot reliable over a large domain?